# InfluxDB and Grafana memory utilization

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I would like to monitor two metrics, memory available and memory used using Telegraf, InfluxDB and Grafana. In Grafana, I have the following metrics:

```
A
SELECT mean("available_percent") FROM "mem" WHERE "host" = 'ubuntu-client' AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time($interval) fill(null)
B
SELECT mean("used_percent") FROM "mem" WHERE "host" = 'ubuntu-client' AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time($interval) fill(null)
```

Each individually displays a nice, bumpy graph. I'm trying to display them on 1 single graph  and then the graphs flat out. Reason is because the values are so different (couple of % vs around 90%).

How can I put them on 1 graph so that both show up relative to each other and I can see the 'bumps'

Comment: Not sure I fully understand what you're trying to do. Grafana allows you to specify multiple queries for a single graph and each query should correspond to a single line on the graph.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by creating a graph with two query's. Alias them for example with `available_percent` and `used_percent`. Then in the `Display Tab` you can add a second Y-Axis via the `Series specific overrides`

[image]